# Eliminating Xamarin Studio iOS API version hints

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I like to make Xamarin Studio happy by fixing/eliminating/suppressing all warnings/hints/etc. in my code.

When I use an API that is not available in a version of iOS supported by my app, I get this:

> Hint: This API requires iOS X.X or later.

[image: Screenshot of 'Hint: This API requires iOS 8.2 or later']

This makes Xamarin Studio sad, with green marks in the gutter:

[image]

I properly check for the existence of the APIs in the standard way (`RespondsToSelector` check), so the code is safe, but Xamarin Studio still shows the hint. I've tried some alternatives to RespondsToSelector, such as `UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion`, but nothing I've tried so far eliminates the hint.

Is there (a) a way to suppress the hint or (b) some sort of version-checking code pattern to use that will satisfy the hint?